# task scheduler + windows 7 + won't run task

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that I can run from its directory giving this command:

```
c:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Folder\V3>C:\Windows\Syste
m32\WScript.exe "c:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Folder\V3\filename.vbs"
```

but if I try and do it from this location c:\

```
c:\>C:\Windows\Syste
m32\WScript.exe "c:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Folder\V3\filename.vbs"
```

I get permission denied, and I do not understand fully.

**What permission do I have to have for this to work?**

Note: 
I am trying to schedule this task in task Scheduler Windows7 which has led me to this question as this is what the task scheduler does.

    I do not have local admin rights.

    found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925908/how-to-start-a-vbs-script-in-windows-7-task-scheduler-with-messagebox) useful re trying to solve this.

    I am just unsure of my permissions.

Comment: useful links relative to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625127/task-scheduler-windows-7) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925908/how-to-start-a-vbs-script-in-windows-7-task-scheduler-with-messagebox)

Answer (score 0):

worked this out see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229716/moving-from-task-scheduler-in-xp-to-windows7)

Basically itt turns out I have to put the location of every script.vbs in the `Start in: (optional)` parmaeter of the `Action` tab for each schedule.